# Удалить объект из массива объектов по значению

Tags: php, массивы

basket.json

```
[
  {
    "item": 13
  },
  {
    "item": 12
  }
]
```

код:

```
$posted_value = 13;
$basketJson = file_get_contents('basket.json');
$usedBasket = json_decode($basketJson, true);

foreach ( $usedBasket as $basket ) {
    foreach ( $basket as $key => $value ) {
        if (( $key = array_search($posted_value, $value)) !== false ) {
            unset($basket[$key]);
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents('basket.json', json_encode($usedBasket));
```

но в файле также остался объект со значением 13. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В foreach по умолчанию передаётся копия массива. Что бы получить доступ к исходному массиву, нужно добавить амперсанд в обеих циклах:

```
foreach ($usedBasket as &$basket)
```

и

```
foreach ($basket as $key => &$value)
```

Если вы изменяете только $basket, то во втором цикле амперсанд можно не добавлять.

---

Для модификации массива было бы удобнее вместо foreach() использовать for() хотя бы потому, что бы не удалять после цикла оставшиеся ссылки. Например:

```
$posted_value = 13;

$basketJson = '[
  {
    "item": 13
  },
  {
    "item": 12
  }
]';

$usedBasket = json_decode($basketJson, true);

for ($i = 0, $all = count($usedBasket); $i < $all; $i++) {
    if ($usedBasket[$i]['item'] === $posted_value) {
        unset($usedBasket[$i]);
    }
}

$usedBasket = array_values($usedBasket);

var_dump($usedBasket);
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> array(1) {
    ["item"]=> int(12)
  }
}
```

Comment: Остался почему-то пустой массив [[],{"item": 12}], я рассчитывал на [{"item": 12}], как это улучшить?

Comment: теперь {"1":{"item":12}} "1" ... такое ощущение что массив надо как-то переиндексировать.

Comment: @GarfieldCat дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$posted_value = 13;

$basketJson = '[
 {
   "item": 13
 },
 {
     "item": 12
  }
]';

$usedBasket = json_decode($basketJson, true);
$Array = [];
   for ($i = 0, $all = count($usedBasket); $i < $all; $i++) {
    if ($usedBasket[$i]['item'] != $posted_value) {
     array_push($Array,$usedBasket[$i]['item']);
   }
}
$basketJson = $Array;
$usedBasket = array_values($usedBasket);`
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]